# How to re render child component in React hook..useEffect

Tags: reactjs

How can i re render this using useeffect geo value getting updated from parent?

```
import React from 'react'
import { compose } from 'recompose'
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap as ReactGoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps'

import Marker from './Marker'

const GoogleMap = compose(withGoogleMap)(({ geo }) => {
  console.log(geo)
  return (
    <ReactGoogleMap
      center={{ lat: geo.latitude, lng: geo.longitude }}
      options={{
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
        zoom: 18,
      }}
    >
      <Marker loc={geo} />
    </ReactGoogleMap>
  )
})

export default GoogleMap
```

Comment: This is child component and from parent geo value getting updated using setstate hook. So need to re render or relaod this component after prop updated

Comment: Why do you need useEffect here, since your component is already wrapped in an HOC which will trigger updates on prop change

Comment: Thank you for replying.but if I want my map to be update on drop-down change event.Dropdown is in parent component, so if I setState in that event will it possible to update map automatically (if state changes). So if setState automatically update UI , when to use useEffect. What scenario where we can use useEffect

Comment: You need to use `useEffect` when you wish to perform sideEffects like making API calls to fetch data or updating certain state when others change. Also useEffect can be used equivalent to lifecycle methods for class components